# Google Analytics reports contain query strings with _bk _bm _bn

Tags: google-analytics

I have many pages in my Google Analytics All Pages report with query strings parameters similar to the example below. Does anyone know which app/search engine/service might be creating links with these query string parameters.

I'd like to exclude them from being tracked in Google Analytics, but I don't want to block them without knowing their origin.

www.example.com/?_bk=example query&_bm=e&_bn=g

Thanks in advance for your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our case they were installed on our URLs during the integration of [Bizible](https://www.bizible.com/) with AdWords, in particular when we implemented the tracking template as they recommend in their documention.

[Understanding Bizible AdWords Tagging](https://support.bizible.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005055868-Understanding-Bizible-AdWords-Tagging?flash_digest=668fa798e989e90e091c2a83e1ab92a82d152914) (Not public - login using your Bizible account)

The line in question (emphasis mine):

> However, the same URL will provide granular data because of the
>   Bizible parameters:
>
> http://example.com/landing-page?myParam=foo&**_bk**={keyword}&**_bt**={creative}&**_bm**={matchtype}&**_bn**={network}

They may use these parameters for other parts of their service other than AdWords integration, but safe to say they are probably related to Bizible.